# Bash read filename and return version number with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to use one or two lines of Bash (that can be run in a command line) to read a folder-name and return the version inside of the name.

So if I have `myfolder_v1.0.13` I know that I can use `echo "myfolder_v1.0.13" | awk -F"v" '{ print $2 }'` and it will return with `1.0.13`.

But how do I get the shell to read the folder name and pipe with the `awk` command to give me the same result without using `echo`? I suppose I could always navigate to the directory and translate the output of `pwd` into a variable somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: As soon as I asked I figured it out. I can use

`result=${PWD##*/}; echo $result | awk -F"v" '{ print $2 }'`

and it gives me what I want. I will leave this question up for others to reference unless someone wants me to take it down.

Comment: There are no "folders" in UNIX, the UNIX term for what Windows refers to as a "folder" is "directory" - that info will make it easier for you to read UNIX tool documentation and find/recognize tools that operate on directories (e.g. `dirname`, `find . -type d`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you don't need an `Awk` at all, here just use `bash` parameter expansion.

```
string="myfolder_v1.0.13"
printf "%s\n" "${string##*v}"
1.0.13
```

Comment: Yes, that works too! Thank you! I am glad that bash has some builtin functions for this.

Comment: @ChristopherSinclair: Note that `result=${PWD##*/} | echo $result | awk -F"v" '{ print $2 }'` won't work. You need to have a `;` after the first command as `result=${PWD##*/}; echo $result | awk -F"v" '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Alright thank you for that I will make sure to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
basename "$(cd "foldername" ; pwd )" | awk -Fv '{print $2}'
```

to get the shell to give you the directory name, but if you really want to use the shell, you could also avoid the use of awk completetly:
Assuming you have the path to the folder with the version number in the parameter "FOLDERNAME":

```
echo "${FOLDERNAME##*v}"
```

This removes the longest prefix matching the glob expression "*v" in the value of the parameter FOLDERNAME.